# How to exclude a specific user from not getting locked-out after the inactive days

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, rhel, pam

I know the PAM rule using **pam_faillock** to lock-out dormant users and not allowing them to login via console or ssh after certain number of inactive days.

But I want to exclude a specific user from not getting locked even after the inactive days when the **pam_faillock** PAM rule is already in place.

I am using **RHEL7.4**

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to avoid user being prevented from login after inactive days expiry.

*1st method*:  as an administrator and by doing "**su**" as that of the locked user, the **lastlog** entry will be updated which will allow him to login. But this would not work if "*pam_lastlog inactive*" rule is added in the **/etc/pam.d/system-auth** and **/etc/pam.d/password-auth** or in the **/etc/pam.d/su**

*2nd Method*: by adding another temporary PAM rule using **pam_succeed_if** module just above the "*pam_lastlog inactive*" rule line

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user in username
auth       required     pam_lastlog.so inactive=5
```